# How to generate Data payload for a smart contract transaction programmatically?

Tags: abi, multisignature

Some wallets, like Gnosis Safe multisig, do not have web3.js support or ABI encoder built-in. How one can create a transaction that calls a smart contract function and originates from such wallets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have ABI files for the smart contract. Then you can use Node.js console, JavaScript or TypeScript to generate a payload for `Data` to trigger a smart contract function call with the transaction.

Steps to make such a call

1. Get ABI files needed for the smart contracts, usually from Github
2. Create a snippet that is pasted in Node.js console for the ABI encoding.
3. Get the result of this snippet to be used as `Data` in the transaction
4. Create a new transaction. `To` field is the smart contract address and `Data` value is the result of the ABI encoding from the script.

Here is an example that uses TypeScript and OpenZeppelin SDK to craft data payload for `approve()` call.

```
import { ZWeb3, Contracts } from '@openzeppelin/upgrades';
import { createProvider } from './src/utils/deploy';

const INFURA_PROJECT_ID = '...';

async function run(): Promise<void> {
  // Initialze
  const provider = createProvider([], INFURA_PROJECT_ID, 'mainnet');
  ZWeb3.initialize(provider);

  // Instiate contracts
  const DawnTokenImpl = Contracts.getFromLocal('DawnTokenImpl');
  const TokenSwap = Contracts.getFromLocal('TokenSwap');
  const token = DawnTokenImpl.at('0x580c8520dEDA0a441522AEAe0f9F7A5f29629aFa');
  const tokenSwap = DawnTokenImpl.at('0x2e776B7BFb8E8307E476BA4B77B21D4532ed47d2');
  const holder = '0xedae4cfB12ECfCDE46853f63aBa76D8EA3CF3871';

  // Read the full balance of the multisig wallet
  const allOfBalance = await token.methods.balanceOf(holder).call();

  // Approve this balance to be used for the token swap
  const dataPayload = token.methods.approve(tokenSwap.address, allOfBalance).encodeABI();
  console.log('Data payload for approve() tx is', dataPayload);
}

run();
```

Example output is

```
Data payload for approve() tx is 0x095ea7b30000000000000000000000002e776b7bfb8e8307e476ba4b77b21d4532ed47d20000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d50b9c6c40cb6192cfce0
```

[Further information how to run console script snippets in OpenZeppelin SDK environment](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/using-openzeppelin-sdk-from-node-typescript-prompt/2716/2).

Answer (score 2):

For [Gnosis MultiSigWallet](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol), I use the following:

```
function submitTransaction(options, msWalletAddr, contractAddr, contractAbi, functionName, functionArgs, privateKey) {
    return sign(options, msWalletAddr, "submitTransaction", [contractAddr, "0", encode(contractAbi, functionName, functionArgs)], privateKey);
}

function confirmTransaction(options, msWalletAddr, transactionId, privateKey) {
    return sign(options, msWalletAddr, "confirmTransaction", [transactionId], privateKey);
}

function executeTransaction(options, msWalletAddr, transactionId, privateKey) {
    return sign(options, msWalletAddr, "executeTransaction", [transactionId], privateKey);
}

function revokeConfirmation(options, msWalletAddr, transactionId, privateKey) {
    return sign(options, msWalletAddr, "revokeConfirmation", [transactionId], privateKey);
}
```

The `options` parameter is an object containing the following fields:

- `price` (gas price)
- `limit` (gas limit)
- `nonce` (transaction nonce)

The functions `sign` and `encode` are implemented as follows:

```
const EthereumTx = require("ethereumjs-tx");

function sign(options, msWalletAddr, actionName, actionArgs, privateKey) {
    const params = {
        value   : 0, 
        chainId : 1,
        gasPrice: Number(options.price), 
        gasLimit: Number(options.limit),
        nonce   : Number(options.nonce),
        to      : msWalletAddr, 
        data    : encode(MultiSigWalletAbi, actionName, actionArgs)
    };
    const ethereumTx = new EthereumTx(params);
    ethereumTx.sign(Buffer.from(privateKey.slice(2), "hex"));
    return ethereumTx.serialize().toString("hex");
}

function encode(contractAbi, functionName, functionArgs) {
    for (const object of contractAbi)
        if (object.name == functionName)
            return web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(object, functionArgs);
    throw new Error("function " + functionName + " does not exist");
}
```

The variables `web3` and `MultiSigWalletAbi` are assumed global and initialized.

---

As you can understand from `value: 0`, the code above supports only functions that do not pass ether, but that can easily be enabled by passing `value` is input.

As you can understand from `chainId: 1`, the code above supports only contracts deployed on mainnet, but that can easily be enabled by passing `chainId` is input.

Comment: Super good information sharing  - thank you once again!

Comment: Also please note that Gnosis Multisig 2.0 a.k.a. Gnosis Safe for Teams is now out.  The transaction signing mechanism seems to be a signature based.